# Output the test shell script status to webpage

Tags: shell

I have created tests using sshUnit2[shUnit2 is a xUnit unit test framework for Bourne based shell scripts]. Once the tests are executed I can see the execution on the console including the test status. I would like to redirect the output including error/exception to a webpage just like rake task in rspec. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, i haven't tried it. I'm new to shell so would need some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

When you type a command in the terminal you'll get a the normal output from stdout. If you want to see errors from stderr you have to redirect them from stderr to stdout by appending `2>&1` to your command (`YOUR_COMMAND 2>&1`).

To view the output from a command in a web browser, you can pipe the output to netcat (e.g. `YOUR_COMMAND 2>&1 | netcat -l -p PORT_NUMBER`). Now the command waits until you navigate your web browser to `localhost:PORT_NUMBER`. After opening the URL, netcat will print some server-client specific stuff and then quits. You can prevent the netcat output by redirecting it to /dev/null (`YOUR_COMMAND 2>&1 | netcat -l -p PORT_NUMBER 2>&1 >/dev/null`).

If you want to keep the "command-output-server" alive after loading the content in the browser, you have to loop over the command. With `while true` you can loop infinitely. So do `while true; do YOUR_COMMAND 2>&1 | netcat -l -p PORT_NUMBER 2>&1 >/dev/null; done` to keep the server alive. With an `&` at the end you can run the whole thing in the background.

For example your final command could look like this:

```
while true; do date 2>&1 | netcat -l -p 8888 2>&1 >/dev/null; done &
```

(Browse to `127.0.0.1:8888` to see the current date and time)